# Turning data frame rows into an R value

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in R:

```
region_loop | test_regions
------      | ------
field1      | POSTAL_DIST_AB
field2      | POSTAL_DIST_AL
field3      | POSTAL_DIST_B
```

and I want to turn each row into an individual R value which would appear beneath the data sets on the right hand side of the R interface. NB: the number of rows within my table can change every time the code is run. The values would be:

```
Value           content of value
field1          "POSTAL_DIST_AB"
field2          "POSTAL_DIST_AL"
field3          "POSTAL_DIST_B"
```

Comment: I have used the help page to insert at table and it results in the above (which doesn't look very well formatted)

Comment: We still need to see the output from dput(df) where df is your data frame as @akrun suggested.  If your data frame is large, you could just use dput(head(df)).

Comment: I've solved this now - will paste the code at the bottom of the question

Comment: Please don't put the answer in your question. You can (and should!) submit your own answer. Then after a brief wait you can click the check mark that will mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 3):

A much better way to do this than using `assign` would be to create a named vector or list:

```
setNames(df$test_regions,df$region_loop)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
name = paste("fields",i,sep="")
assign(name,df[i,1])
}
```